# WPF TextBlock gradient

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i convert this from XAML to c#

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Cell0" FontSize="72" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="50">
            <TextBlock.Background>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="Cyan" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </TextBlock.Background>1</TextBlock>
```

I've already tried like this

```
RadialGradientBrush radialGradientBrush = new RadialGradientBrush();
            radialGradientBrush.GradientOrigin = new Point(5, 5);
            radialGradientBrush.Center = new Point(5, 5);
            radialGradientBrush.RadiusX = 5;
            radialGradientBrush.RadiusY = 5;
            radialGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Cyan, 0.0));
            radialGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.White, 1));
Cell0.Background = radialGradientBrush
```

However that don't work, then ive tried replacing the 5 at Radius to 10 and the Cyan color appears, but not as an gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize only the same elements that you do in XAML so in your case don't set `GradientOrigin`, `Center` or `RadiusX`/`RadiusY` and simplify it to

```
RadialGradientBrush radialGradientBrush = new RadialGradientBrush();
radialGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Cyan, 0.0));
radialGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.White, 1));
Cell0.Background = radialGradientBrush;
```

Comment: Great, Thanks i tried removing the radius, but off cause didn't try removing the rest

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   RadialGradientBrush myRadialGradientBrush = new RadialGradientBrush();
    myRadialGradientBrush.GradientOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    myRadialGradientBrush.Center = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    myRadialGradientBrush.RadiusX = 0.5;
    myRadialGradientBrush.RadiusY = 0.5;
    myRadialGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(
                    new GradientStop(Colors.Cyan, 0.0));
    myRadialGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add(
                    new GradientStop(Colors.White, 1.0));

    cell0.Fill = myRadialGradientBrush;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridLabelColor" StartPoint="0.25,0" EndPoint="0.65,1" Opacity=".5">
        <GradientStop Color="AliceBlue" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Silver" Offset=".35"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Navy" Offset="0.85"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</UserControl.Resources>
```